# Undefined variable causes huge verbose output from `esm.js`

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not sure why, but since upgrading to Node v16 from Node v14, I get this error only when I run node like `node -r esm` and there is a ReferenceError like:

`ReferenceError: myVar is not defined`

It causes a massive, 5000 line output of the esm.js module. How can I get rid of this?

```
const __global__ = this;(function (require, module, __shared__) { var __shared__;const e=module,t={Array:global.Array,Buffer:global.Buffer,Error:g
lobal.Error,EvalError:global.EvalError,Function:global.Function,JSON:global.JSON,Object:global.Object,Promise:global.Promise,RangeError:global.Ran
geError,ReferenceError:global.ReferenceError,Reflect:global.Reflect,SyntaxError:global.SyntaxError,TypeError:global.TypeError,URIError:global.URIE
rror,eval:global.eval},r=global.console;module.exports=(function(e){var t={};function r(i){if(t[i])return t[i].exports;var n=t[i]={i:i,l:!1,export
s:{}};return e[i].call(n.exports,n,n.exports,r),n.l=!0,n.exports}return r.d=function(e,t,r){Reflect.defineProperty(e,t,{configurable:!0,enumerable
:!0,get:r})},r.n=function(e){return e.a=e,function(){return e}},r(r.s=2)})([(function(e,t){var r;t=e.exports=$,"object"==typeof process&&process,r
=function(){},t.SEMVER_SPEC_VERSION="2.0.0";var i=256,n=Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER||9007199254740991,s=t.re=[],a=t.src=[],o=0,u=o++;a[u]="0|[1-9]\\d*
";var l=o++;a[l]="[0-9]+";var c=o++;a[c]="\\d*[a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z0-9-]*";var p=o++;a[p]="("+a[u]+")\\.("+a[u]+")\\.("+a[u]+")";var h=o++;a[h]="("+a[l
]+")\\.("+a[l]+")\\.("+a[l]+")";var f=o++;a[f]="(?:"+a[u]+"|"+a[c]+")";var d=o++;a[d]="(?:"+a[l]+"|"+a[c]+")";var m=o++;a[m]="(?:-("+a[f]+"(?:\\."
+a[f]+")*))";var v=o++;a[v]="(?:-?("+a[d]+"(?:\\."+a[d]+")*))";var g=o++;a[g]="[0-9A-Za-z-]+";var y=o++;a[y]="(?:\\+("+a[g]+"(?:\\."+a[g]+")*))";v
ar x=o++,b="v?"+a[p]+a[m]+"?"+a[y]+"?";a[x]="^"+b+"$";var w="[v=\\s]*"+a[h]+a[v]+"?"+a[y]+"?",E=o++;a[E]="^"+w+"$";var S=o++;a[S]="((?:<|>)?=?)";v
ar R=o++;a[R]=a[l]+"|x|X|\\*";var P=o++;a[P]=a[u]+"|x|X|\\*";var _=o++;a[_]="[v=\\s]*("+a[P]+")(?:\\.("+a[P]+")(?:\\.("+a[P]+")(?:"+a[m]+")?"+a[y]
+"?)?)?";var k=o++;a[k]="[v=\\s]*("+a[R]+")(?:\\.("+a[R]+")(?:\\.("+a[R]+")(?:"+a[v]+")?"+a[y]+"?)?)?";var I=o++;a[I]="^"+a[S]+"\\s*"+a[_]+"$";var
 A=o++;a[A]="^"+a[S]+"\\s*"+a[k]+"$";var N=o++;a[N]="(?:^|[^\\d])(\\d{1,16})(?:\\.(\\d{1,16}))?(?:\\.(\\d{1,16}))?(?:$|[^\\d])";var C=o++;a[C]="(?
:~>?)";var O=o++;a[O]="(\\s*)"+a[C]+"\\s+",s[O]=RegExp(a[O],"g");var T=o++;a[T]="^"+a[C]+a[_]+"$";var M=o++;a[M]="^"+a[C]+a[k]+"$";var L=o++;a[L]=
"(?:\\^)";var D=o++;a[D]="(\\s*)"+a[L]+"\\s+",s[D]=RegExp(a[D],"g");var F=o++;a[F]="^"+a[L]+a[_]+"$";var j=o++;a[j]="^"+a[L]+a[k]+"$";var V=o++;a[
V]="^"+a[S]+"\\s*("+w+")$|^$";var G=o++;a[G]="^"+a[S]+"\\s*("+b+")$|^$";var B=o++;a[B]="(\\s*)"+a[S]+"\\s*("+w+"|"+a[_]+")",s[B]=RegExp(a[B],"g");
v..........
```

How can I stop node from printing this to the console?

Answer (score -1):

Try resetting your computer. It works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).